# how can i read each word of a line from a file separately?

Tags: python, file, class

so the problem I came across is that I need to read each word of a line from a line one by one and repeat it for the whole file. each of the words are separated from each other by the # sign, e.g
**2016/2017#Southeast_Kootenay#Mount_Baker_Secondary#STANDARD#COURSE_MARKS#99.0#71.0#88.0#49.0**
after that I need to assign each value to the appropriate element of a class, for example:
school_years would be 2016/2017, district_name would be Southeast_Kootenay and etc.
the thing is that I have clue how to do it, I managed to extract the first word from a file but couldn't do it for the whole line and let alone the whole file, this is the code I used.

```
def word_return():
  for lines in file:
      for word in lines.split('#'):
          return word
```

any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Change the `return` to `yield`, and while calling call `list(word_return())`

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a single `word`. Remove last `for` and return the entire list like this if you want to get only the first line:
(Assuming `file` is a list of lines resulted from `file = open("file.txt", "r").readlines()`)

```
def word_return():
  for line in open("yourFile.txt", "r").readlines():
      return lines.split('#')
```

If you want to return a list that will contain a list for each line, check the following:

```
def word_return():
  allLines = []
  for line in open("yourFile.txt", "r").readlines():
      allLines.append(lines.split('#'))
  return allLines
```